# Patching Magento

Tags: patches, supee-8788, magento1.9.2.4

Does this look right to you regarding output during a patch.  This was run on a backup set of files to check whether it would work correctly on my live store.  This is actually the first time I've had to run a patch so I'm a little hesitant.  Also didn't receive a "Patch was applied/reverted successfully" output.

Output returned this:

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2016-10-11-07-03-46.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
can't find file to patch at input line 447
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
|index 2d52d0c..fc7fe93 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 393 (offset 18 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
can't find file to patch at input line 1718
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
|index 43ef4e7..010e3f8 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/Transaction.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design/Images.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design.phtml
patching file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
patching file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
patching file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
patching file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
patching file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your files

```
app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
```

and

```
app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
```

are missing ?
Try to restore them and then apply the patch again.

Comment: It looks like the copy to a backup directory for testing purposes didn't complete correctly and as a result I don't actually have either of those in the folder.  I will obviously re-try.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The patch wasn't applied successfully.  Near the top of the output is

> ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

and also this a bit further down

> can't find file to patch at input line 447 Perhaps you used the wrong
>   -p or --strip option?